# PhoneGap-приложение под Android перестало отправлять Ajax-запросы - в чём может быть причина?

Tags: android, ajax, phonegap, framework7

Совсем недавно перестало работать PhoneGap-приложение под Anrdoid'oм, интерфейс которого был построен на базе: [Framework7](https://framework7.io/) (версия **1.4.2**). Это же самое приложение под iOS работает без нареканий.

Естественно, первым делом я взялся за отладку по инструкции: http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/debugging/

Отладка мне ничего не дала в плане каких-либо JavaScript-ошибок:
[image]

Однако, стало понятно что приложение не может отправлять Ajax-запросы:
[image]
вернее они как видно висят в статусе: Pending

На сервере куда летят запросы я ставил - ловушку: запросы не доходят туда...

**Что делать? Куда копать? С чем это может быть связано?**

Answer (score 0):

Причина оказалась банальной - **неверно установлен корневой сертификат для SSL на сервере**. 
Подошло время обновления и после переустановки всё заработало.

p.s.: кстати приложение работало через HTTP, а через HTTPS нет...